# get data between two Dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySql database. and I am executing query like this:

```
select * 
from Request
where 
DATE_FORMAT(created_On,'%e/%m/%Y') between DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() - 30, '%e/%m/%Y') and DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%e/%m/%Y')
```

it will return blank, means no records in result.

but if I write like this

```
select * 
from Request
where 
DATE_FORMAT(created_On,'%e/%m/%Y') between DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() - 27, '%e/%m/%Y') and DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%e/%m/%Y')
```

It will fetch 100 hundred rows.

I want to ask that why i am subtract 30 days from current Date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your date columns are proper `DATETIME` or `DATE` fields, you should not use `DATE_FORMAT()`. Use [`DATE_SUB()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) to subtract 30 days:

If `created_On` is `DATETIME`, use `DATE()` to truncate off the time portion:

```
SELECT * 
from Request
where 
  DATE(created_On) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND CURDATE()
```

If `created_On` is `DATE`, just use:

```
SELECT * 
from Request
where 
  created_On BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the TO_DAYS function on the dates which allows you to compare dates and datetime fields:

```
SELECT * from Request
where TO_DAYS(created_On) BETWEEN TO_DAYS(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)) AND TO_DAYS(CURDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you at least first post a sample of your data and Identify `created_on` first, so that we could establish a proper analysis of your question? Because to be honest when you are using between the first assumption would be `created_on` would be of type date, but then again the date_format function transform your date into a string so using between with a string as a value will have a different result than using between with a date